# Включение\Выключение QDockWidget в PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Как сделать закрываемые части приложения, как в QtDesigner, Через выпадающее окно в вверху приложения?

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста пример, который у вас есть и лучше объясните что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QDockWidget` имеет функцию `toggleViewAction()` которая возращает `QAction`. Если добавить этот QAction в QMenu то будет то что я хотел